# What tools can I use to get WordPress updates on a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, rss, wordpress

I have been using the RSS Graffiti app to get updates from WordPress onto my Facebook page. This generally works fairly well, giving me a photo thumbnail, title, and short description.

My thoughts on this:

- I'm not crazy that the update has the orange RSS Graffiti icon at the bottom, but that's not such a big deal.
- Posting to a Facebook page with an App (like RSSS Graffiti) has less impact on the feeds of the people who "like" your page than if you were to add the update manually.

So what tools can I use to get WordPress updates on a Facebook page?

Maybe RSS Graffiti is the "best" solution for this sort of thing but I'd really like to hear what tools everyone else is using.

Comment: I came here to ask the same question, but wasn't even aware of RSS Graffiti. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a Wordpress plugin [Add Link To Facebook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-link-to-facebook/) to post to updates from my blog to Facebook. The setup is a little involved as you need to set up your own Facebook App as well, but not particularly hard and the guide is well written. It lets you (optionally) write a description, choose a thumbnail and title that get posted.

Comment: +1 as promised. thanks for sharing! I look forward to playing with this!